# DTO Mapping for RESt service of type GET

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Developing a REST service in Spring BOOT application.

This is the input json

```
{
    "rcode": 122,
    "ecode": [11, 12]
}
```

Controller code

```
 @RequestMapping("/getPersonDTOList")
    public List < PersonDTO > getPersonDTOList(
        @RequestParam(value = "personDTO") String personDTO){

    //how can I map this to DTO

        }
```

//DTO

```
 public class PersonDTO {
        private Int rcode;
        private List<Int> ecode;

        }
```

How can I map this string to DTO in spring BOOT, Since this is GET we need to do it manually.

Comment: Why not it is POST ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha Probably because the request is not changing anything on the server (ie to the database)

Comment: How are you passing json to rest-service?

Comment: @Abhijeet I can pass it as a request param too, not necessary to send as request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GET` method does not carry any body data.

You either:

- Change your API to `POST` method (which is supported by default with `@RequestMapping`

  ```
  @RequestMapping("/getPersonDTOList")
  public List < PersonDTO > getPersonDTOList(@RequestBody PersonDTO person)
  ```
- Change your API to accept `@RequestParameter` instead of `@RequestBody`:

  ```
  @RequestMapping("/getPersonDTOList")
  public List < PersonDTO > getPersonDTOList(@RequestParam("rcode") int rcode, @RequestParam("ecode") List<Integer> ecode )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I am not so experiensed but if you use @RequestMapping I think you have to set a type also:

```
 @RequestMapping("/getPersonDTOList", method = RequestMethod.POST ) // or GET...
```

You can also use  @PostMapping , @GetMapping, etc.

```
@PostMapping("/getPersonDTOList")
public PersonDTO getPersonDTOList(@RequestBody PersonDTO person){ 
     return person;
}
```

I think this is only valid only with @RestController